# Let $\forall n\in \mathbb{N} : \sum a_n >0$ converges series , Prove/disprove $\sum \frac {a_n*a_{n+1}}{a_n+a_{n+1}}$ converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm stuck in this question and have no clue.
I tried using contradiction with the series $\frac {1}{n^2}$ and similar series but got only "converges".

My only understanding was that for big enough $n$ the sequence $a_n$ is decreasing and so $a_n \ge a_{n_1}$.
and because $a_n>0$ for all $n$ then by ration test $\rightarrow \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=q<1$.
I though about changing the series to $\frac {a_{n+1}}{(1+\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n})}$ and trying to prove that the sequence is not converging to $0$ but failed to.

Any clues about proving or contradiction samples?
I can't seem to prove or find contradiction :(

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n >0$ and $\sum a_n$ is convergent then $0 <\frac {a_na_{n+1}}{a_n+a_{n+1}}<a_n$ so $\sum\frac {a_na_{n+1}}{a_n+a_{n+1}}$ is convergent.

Comment: wow this is so simple and I didn't even think about it